# Result duplication while crawling Twitter

Tags: python, twitter

```
while(page<=500):
    tweets=api.GetSearch("#Burma",per_page=100)
```

Why it gives me so much duplicated result . It give me just one page and repeat it 500 times. It gives me the same tweets as of first page . Can anyone please give me a clue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask twitter for each page separately; in your loop you keep asking for the same page each time, without passing the page number to the search query:

```
import twitter

api = twitter.Api()
page = 1
while page <= 500:
    tweets = api.GetSearch("#Burma", page=page, per_page=100)
    for t in tweets:
        print t.text
    page += 1
```

You don't need to use a `while` loop either, you can simplify the code by using a `for` loop instead, combined with the `xrange()` function:

```
api = twitter.Api()
for page in xrange(1, 501):
    tweets = api.GetSearch("#Burma", page=page, per_page=100)
    for t in tweets:
        print t.text
```